# django models table with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I want to give access to Messages with another table to the Message table, many users can access message. 
I am confused on how to declare the foreign keys

```
   class Message(models.Model):

            ID = models.CharField(_("ID"), max_length=140)
            body = models.TextField(_("Body"))
            permission=models.ForeignKey(Permission,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=
            _("permission"),null=True,black=True)
```

Second Table :

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    #multiple users have to access to Message 


    Users = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='access', 
    verbose_name=_("UserWithAccess"),   on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs import User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Then call the User model within your Foreign key field:

```
Users = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='access', 
verbose_name=_("UserWithAccess"),   on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Hope this helps. 
Regards